# Babel react-native-reanimated/plugin not working

Tags: react-native, expo, react-animated

Currently trying to use react-native-reanimated with react drawer style navigation and expo keeps giving me a error of:

> Export namespace should be first transformed by
> `@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from`.

code:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      "react-native-reanimated/plugin"
    ],
}
```

code from the component i want to use react navigation:

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

const Tab = createDrawerNavigator();
```

** if it helps i am also using this drawer styled navigation nested inside a bottom tab navigator in my app.

Answer (score 0):

the plugin is not supposed to go into expo config, as it is babel plugin, not expo one. To fix it, move it into your babel.config.js:

```
// minimal example
module.exports = api => ({ plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'], presets: [] })
```